# UIkit and will_paginate on Rails 5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, uikit, will-paginate

I'm using UIkit for styling a Rails app and use the `will_paginate` gem for paginating the results of a category. I know there is a way to bootstrap the `will_paginate` gem. Is there any solution for paginating the gem with UIkit?

Comment: Ruby version 5 is not out yet. I think you mean Rails 5.0.

Comment: Yes, corrected. Thank you